# Moving Windows 7 to a new drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, disk-cloning

I have a Win 7 64 bit system with two 1 terabyte drives - each with multiple partitions. When I built the machine 6 months ago, I repurposed an older drive as the primary drive, but this drive now shows some minor degradation in the S.M.A.R.T.  - since I'm moving to this machine as my primary workstation I wanted a new drive, even though right now no drives are failing.

I used Acronis Disk Director [standalone from CD] to clone the drive exactly as it is - no resizing- partitions C D E F G. Pulled out the old drive and tried to boot and it started Windows and asked for the original Win7 DVD. Tried to get it to repair and was not successful. I deleted the C partition and copied again, then tried a manual repair using http://www.tomshardware.com/news/win7-windows-7-mbr,10036.html

bootrec.exe /FixMbr
 bootrec.exe /FixBoot 
 bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd

Still will not start Windows

Once more deleted and recopied C:, but used MiniTool Partition Wizard instead of Acronis, then did a manual recovery again but used another reference [sorry I lost the link] to do the repair, this suggested multiple automatic repairs intermixed with using bootrec.exe - I ended up with a message like "pwnative program not found skipping autocheck" when starting Windows. I found a solution in http://download.cnet.com/MiniTool-Partition-Wizard-Home-Edition/9241-2094_4-12137093.html?messageID=10822927  - basically MiniTool Partition Wizard messes up in Win 7/64.

After applying the fix - I finally can start Win 7 from the new drive, having spent at least 8 hours messing around.

My question is - why is this so difficult? -  I've done drive cloning in Windows XP many many times  and it just works with no hassle. My concern is what happens in the future if I get a drive failure and have to recover again.

Comment: "My question is - why is this so difficult?"  This is not a valid question for SU, as it would be completely opinion-based. VTC.

Comment: Ok, I'm asking "What is the correct way to do this for next time?" - but I would think that the answer to that is opinion based also, based on answers I have seen to similar questions.

Comment: The "right" way according to MS: Use Windows 7's built in System Image tool and create a backup of your Windows 7 install to an external hard disk. Install new hard drive, boot from your Windows 7 DVD and choose to restore a system image and point to the location where the System Image is backed up.

Comment: I think I looked at that, but it wanted to back up my C,D,and G drives - [which I had already done] and that would take several hours, and I think I would need another spare work drive. However, for next time - it does seem the first thing to try

Answer (score 0):

It would have been easier to take your two drives and put them into a seperate PC. You should then transfer the files over from the drives in that PC, and then put the drives back in to the first PC. Then, boot up into the second drive and change the partitions to their default.